# Conjectural nonvanishing of some combinatorial sums (6j symbols)

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-functions

From various considerations and with the help of J. Van der Jeugt, I was led to conjecture the following property of a class of [Wigner 6j-symbols](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wigner6j-Symbol.html):
for any integers $k,m$ with $m\ge k\ge 2$, 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & k & k \\
\frac{m}{2} & \frac{m}{2} & \frac{m}{2}
\end{array}
\right\}\ \neq\ 0
$$
except for the special case $k=2$, $m=3$.

Using Racah's single sum formula this amounts to the nonvanishing of the combinatorial sum
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}
(-1)^n\ 
\left(\begin{array}{c} n+1 \\ 3k+1 \end{array}\right)\ 
\left(\begin{array}{c} k \\ n-k-m \end{array}\right)^3\ 
$$
with the usual convention that binomials are zero if the arguments are out of range.

> Any ideas on how to prove this?

BTW, the exception
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 2 & 2 \\
\frac{3}{2} & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{3}{2}
\end{array}
\right\}\ =\ 0
$$
has an interesting representation-theoretic interpretation (see [this article](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/12/2/001/meta) by P. Minnaert).

Also note that the signs of these symbols look quite complicated.
Using a matrix plot on Mathematica for the output of

`Table[Sign[SixJSymbol[{2+i, 2+i, 2+i}, {(2+i +j)/2, (2+i+j)/2, (2+i+j)/2}]],`

`{i, 0, 200}, {j, 0, 200}]`

produces this picture:
[image]

The exceptional zero mentioned above is the tiny white square in the top left corner.

Note that following Gerhard's suggestion of looking at the problem mod 3 one can rule out zeros away from the white spots in:
[image]

The above picture comes from using Fermat's Little Theorem to get rid of the third power mod 3 and the identity
$$
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}
(-1)^n\ 
\left(\begin{array}{c} n+1 \\ 3k+1 \end{array}\right)\ 
\left(\begin{array}{c} k \\ n-k-m \end{array}\right)
\ =\ (-1)^m
\left(\begin{array}{c} k+m+1 \\ 2k+1 \end{array}\right)\ .
$$
This still leaves a piece of Swiss cheese.

Comment: Do you know the behaviour of these sums mod 3 or mod 7?  Gerhard "Prefers To Add Smaller Sums" Paseman, 2018.07.04

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Indeed, looking at suitable congruences might be more promising than real-variable methods/inequalitiies, given how complicated the signs are. I didn't try mod p methods. Do you see interesting congruences?

Comment: Mod p methods may not work, as the $6j$ symbol with $k=p-1$ and $m=p$ is a multiple of $p$ when $p$ is prime, but the value itself is not 0.

Comment: @Bullet51: The case $m=k+1$ is too easy anyway.

Comment: I have not computed these sums modulo any prime. I chose 3 and 7 because you can transform the sums to get simpler expressions (x^3 to x or 1 or -1 or 0).  The hope is that you can say for which n the sum is not a multiple of 3 or 7.  Gerhard "...And Then Further Inspiration Strikes... " Paseman, 2018.07.05.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: I tried your mod 3 suggestion which helps a little. See edited question.

Comment: Rather than write out an answer, I will suggest rewriting n=i+k+m, have the index i go from 0 to k/2 or just short of that, and then rewrite as (k choose i)^3 times a sum or difference of two binomial terms involving i. Now when m is large enough, the cubed term changes faster with i than the sum or difference, so that your alternating sum is nonzero by monotonicity.  Gerhard "Overlooks Some Details In Comment" Paseman, 2018.07.09.